# (Flask) WTForm gets rendered with wrong values

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

I am currently working on a web-application based "database-explorer" for a university project.
Basically I create a site for each relation of the database, where the user can view the data and additionally I want them to be able to add data.

For that I use wtforms. I take the inputs, create a simple "SQL string" with it and execute it.
To make the input easier, I want to use dynamic SelectFields.

This is my approute:

```
@app.route('/table/fact_angestellte')
def fact_angestellte():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM dim_rolle WHERE ro_rolle !='Ansprechpartner' AND ro_rolle != 'Teilnehmer';")
        choicesRolle = mycursor.fetchall()
        form = InsertAngestelltenForm(choicesRolle)
        print(form.choicesRolle)
        mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM fact_angestellte INNER JOIN dim_rolle ON fact_angestellte.an_rolle_fk = dim_rolle.ro_id_pk;")
        data = mycursor.fetchall()
        return render_template('tables/fact_angestellte.html', data=data, form=form)
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

The form gets created successfully and if I try to print form.choicesRolle (in the approute), it also gives me the correct output in the console. But when I go on my website, the SelectField still has the default value of choicesRolle.

```
class InsertAngestelltenForm(FlaskForm): 
    choicesRolle =[]
    nachname = StringField('Nachname', validators=[DataRequired()])
    vorname = StringField('Vorname',validators=[DataRequired()])
    geschlecht = SelectField('Geschlecht', choices=[('maennlich', 'männlich'), ('weiblich', 'weiblich')], validators=[DataRequired()])
    postleitzahl = StringField('Postleitzahl | FK', validators=[DataRequired()])
    strasse = StringField('Straße und Nummer', validators=[DataRequired()])
    rolle = SelectField('Rolle', choices=choicesRolle, validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Eintrag hinzufügen')

    def __init__(self, choicesRolle):
        super().__init__()
        self.choicesRolle = choicesRolle
        print(self.choicesRolle)
```

So my problem is: the object has the correct attributes, but somehow they don't "reach" the template.
Any help is appreciated.
Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the WTForms documentation, the `choices` keyword is only evaluated [once](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/fields/?highlight=coerce#wtforms.fields.SelectField). In your example, this means it's evaluating to the empty array you set in the `choicesRolle` class attribute, and that's what's being passed to Flask.  You need to set the choices after the form is instantiated, not during it.

On your form class, remove the entire `__init__` method, the `choicesRolle` class attribute, and the `choices` parameter from the `rolle` SelectField. Then, in your `fact_angestellte` view function, set the form's choices after you instantiate it, as follows:

```
choicesRolle = mycursor.fetchall()
form = InsertAngestelltenForm()
form.rolle.choices = choicesRolle
```

This should work...let me know. Note that I'm not sure what data is being returned from `mycursor.fetchall()` as you don't really describe, but the SelectField choices needs to be a list of values...WTForms by default coerces each value to unicode.

Comment: Thank you so much.
Your answer works like a charm.

Happy holidays! Stay safe!